# Triple integral to calculate the volume of pyramid vs it's formula

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

It is well known the formula to calculate the volume of a pyramid:
$V=\frac {1} {3} bh$, where where $b$ is the area of the base and $h$ the height from the base to the apex.

However I need to compare calculating of the volume via triple integral as well and make sure the results are the same.

The pyramid is bounded by planes:
$x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$ and the plane $\alpha$: $9x-y-3z=54$.
So, I need to find $b$ and $h$ to calculate the volume via the formula. Then to calculate the triple integral with no clear boundaries?

Comment: Do you know how to find the coordinates of the $4$ vertices?

Comment: @peterway, thank you. Finally I found the volume. It's 972, right?